# Can shard key in MemSQL have NULLs?

Tags: sharding, singlestore

What are the rules regarding shard key and key for clustered columnStore ?

I need to make a column as Shard key and also for Clustered columnStore, but it may contain Nulls

What will be the impact of keeping a Nullable column as Shard key ?

I have already tested out the data load using this column and on a high-level, everything looks good for the first batch, but will it break anything while writing or reading down the line ?

```
CREATE TABLE test (
name varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
update_date date DEFAULT NULL,
SHARD KEY (update_date) USING CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

NULL values are allowed in shard keys and columnstore keys, and function like any other value - so if you define shard key on a column with some NULLs then all null values will be placed on the same partition.